# Objective-C - Changing Inactive UITabBar Image Colour

Tags: cocoa-touch

I'm trying to find a way to change the tint colour for inactive images on a UITabBar - here is an image of my current progress
[image]

I'm trying to change the colour of the gray image to, currently, any other colour, without any luck. Here is the code I am using:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

I've been searching on Google for some way to make this work but am having no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your are trying to achieve displaying of the actual image at the UITabBar then use the following code:

`tabBarItem.image = [tabImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];`

and if you want to display image in original condition for the selected then use the following :

`tabBarItem.selectedImage = [tabImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];`

these two are alternative to the deprecated methods `setFinishedSelectedImage:` and `withFinishedUnselectedImage:`

Comment: I'm not trying to do any of these things - I just want to set the colour of the Image in it's inactive state.

Comment: So you need to use `tabBarItem.image` that will set the color when it is inactive. You can use the image as a template, and it will accept a tintColor as usual.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this one at a time for each tab bar button as follows:

```
UIImage *rawImage = [[myVC tabBarItem] image];
[[myVC tabBarItem] setFinishedSelectedImage:[rawImage imageWithColorMask:[UIColor grayColor]] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[rawImage imageWithColorMask:[UIColor greenColor]]];
```

EDIT:
Above is the best choice if you want to support iOS before iOS 7, but this method is deprecated. For iOS 7 and above you can just set your tab bar item's image to an image which specifies that you don't want iOS to do color masking for you, as follows:

```
// assuming you have a UIImage ready to go...
myImage = [myImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
[[myVC tabBarItem] setSelectedImage:myImage];
```

Comment: p.s. it took me quite a while to track this down and test various solutions myself, as I did it my app a few months back.

Comment: This code is deprecated in iOS 7, Apple suggests moving to UIAppearance and tintColor in the WWDC '13 videos.

Comment: yeah well, my app runs on ios5 and ios6 too. Apple deprecates stuff early and I usually find the marketplace lets me change to the new APIs and bump my oldest supported version about a year later.

Comment: See my answer for the non deprecated alternative.

Comment: My App is an iOS 7 App and I'm not aiming for backwards compatibility - would you recommend using this even if it's deprecated?

Comment: honestly no, Sam's answer would be a better choice if you know you never need to support iOS < 7. Darn it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a two-step process:

1) Create image with UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate

```
tabBarItem.image = [tabImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
```

2) Subclass UIViewController and contribute to `-(void)tintColorDidChange`

```
- (void) tintColorDidChange {

  switch (self.tintAdjustmentMode) {

    case UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal: {
        tabBarItem.tintColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
    }
      break;

    case UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed: {
        tabBarItem.tintColor = [UIColor magentaColor];
    }
      break;

    case UIViewTintAdjustmentModeAutomatic: {
        tabBarItem.tintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }
      break;
  }
}
```

`-(void)tintColorDidChange` will fire whenever the tintColor is changed by the system.

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm pretty new to Objective-C and Cocoa, where do I set `tabBarItem.image` and where do I find the name of my Tab Bar Item (`tabBarItem`)? Thanks

Comment: @ThomasMosey `tabBarItem` is a property of UIViewController; it is a UITabBarItem that the UITabBarController uses to display access to the view controller.  I have modified my answer above; the child view controller needs to handle `tintColorDidChange` for it's `tabBarItem` property.